# Why bq query command writes only 100 rows to file?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export `bq query` result of a view(that as more than 4000 records) to local file but it writes only 100 records. Why? Is there way to get all records of a view to written to local file?

```
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false "select * from `myproject.mydataset.myview`" > D:/out.csv
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference):

> --max_rows or -n
>
> An integer specifying the number of rows to return in the query results. The default value is 100.

So you need to pass `-n 4000` to return at most 4000 rows, for example.

Comment: Great. It worked. However, the first line of the file is a empty row. Any suggestions to remove the unwanted line? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `tail`? `bq query ... | tail -n 2 > file.csv`

Comment: You may prefer `bq query ... | tail -n +2 > file.csv` (keeps header) or `bq query ... | tail -n +3 > file.csv` (removes header)